# How can I set the Overlay container property when using OverlayTrigger?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using the OverlayTrigger component to get hover behavior for tooltips, and therefore not using the Overlay component directly. The Overlay component has a [container](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlays-container) property that I'd like to use to remedy the tooltip getting cut off by its natural container element.

I've attempted to pass a `popperConfig` object, but that's not working. I've also tried adding a `container` attribute to the OverlayTrigger component.

```
<Container fluid className='flex-fill' ref={rowContainer}>
    ... 

    <OverlayTrigger delay={{show: 500}} overlay={renderUserTooltip}
                    popperConfig={{container: rowContainer}}>
        <FaUser/>
    </OverlayTrigger>
```

How can I set the container for the Overlay when the Overlay component isn't directly used?

Comment: I guess you should pass the `rowContainer` ref to the `<FaUser/>` component instead, as implemented on [this example from the official docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#customizing-trigger-behavior) using the function form. Which expects a `ref` from the destructured function arguments.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by remedy the tooltip getting cut off by its natural container element :) The tooltip disappear when you hover over the tooltip itself and you want to prevent that (so keep the tooltip visible as long as the user hover over the trigger OR the tooltip component)?

Comment: It's not about appearing and disappearing. It's about fitment. I'd like to change the location at which the tooltip (or popover, or whatever) is injected into the DOM. That's what the `container` attribute handles. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React bootstrap doesn't have a `container` prop or something similar (I mean it has a `target` prop but as [this part of the docs suggests](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger-props), for the `OverlayTrigger` the type is null, so it doesn't accept values and I don't think you can trick it to accept (and I don't think it would be wise to try).

But a pretty nice example, that shows some sort of a workaround in my opinion, can also be find in the docs, under [customizing-trigger-behavior](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#customizing-trigger-behavior).

Starting from that example, if you need your trigger to be totally separated from the container an option is to just wrap everything in a big container that receives `({ ref, ...triggerHandler })` and all is left is to give your `container` the ref, and the trigger to your `FaUser` component. So something like:

```
<OverlayTrigger
  placement="bottom"
  overlay={<Tooltip id="button-tooltip-2">Check out this avatar</Tooltip>}
>
  {({ containerRef, ...triggerHandler }) => (
    <Container fluid className='flex-fill' ref={containerRef}>
      ...
      <FaUser/>
    </Container>
  )}
</OverlayTrigger>
```

I also created a [sandbox with a minimal reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/s/overlaytrigger-bootstrap-forked-48oivb?file=/src/index.js).